# Stuck in setuping CSS static file in Django

Tags: python, django

I had tried to setup static files in Django but failed.

I have the following directory structure

```
app
 |
 |- manage.py
 |- requirements.txt
 |- static
 |     |
 |     |- css
 |         |
 |         |- snapweb.css
 |
 |
 }- templates
 |- web
     |
     |- __init__.py
     |- settings.py
     |- urls.py
     |- wsgi.py
```

## /app/web/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
import logging

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

## /app/web/settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

---

Take note that, I didn't run `python manage.py collectstatic`. As, if I want to run, I will get the following warning, which I have no idea how to solve it.

```
/app # python manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /app/static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:
```

---

So, my problem is, I feel confused on my app behavior.

The following URL works. I didn't expect it to work, as I don't see `/app/static/admin/css/base.css` file exist. **Where does Django pick up the file?**

```
https://localhost:2053/static/admin/css/base.css
```

---

I also confused, for the following URL not working. Even though file `/app/static/css/snapweb.css` is there. **Why Django doesn't pick up the file?**

```
https://localhost:2053/static/css/snapweb.css
```

---

I wish both URLs, `https://localhost:2053/static/admin/css/base.css` and `https://localhost:2053/static/css/snapweb.css` will work. **Is there any setup I had missed?**

Also, how I can run `python manage.py collectstatic` successfully, without overwriting my `/app/static`?

Comment: `'django.contrib.admin'`  must be a registered in `INSTALLED_APPS`. It loads admin modules required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you seem to be missing the django distinction between apps and the project (given you have named your project "app").  The project is what has `manage.py` and `settings.py`.  The apps are what have `models.py` files.

Given you are using static files from the admin app as well as your own, you are going to need to do some restructuring.  Django is looking for static files in `STATIC_ROOT`.  In a "proper" setup, you're supposed to put static files in directories specific to your apps (as opposed to your project).  The project static file (pointed to by `STATIC_ROOT` should have nothing you defined in it since that's where Django is going to put all your files when you run `collectstatic`.

Try moving your static folder to be a subdirectory of your app folder ("web/static") and running `collectstatic`.

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have idea why `https://localhost:2053/static/css/snapweb.css` doesn't work, even though `/app/static/css/snapweb.css` is there?

Comment: I've changed my recommendation.  Hope this helps

Comment: After moving `/app/static` folder to `/app/web/static`, and run `collectstatic`, I can see `/app/static/admin/css` is created. But, `/app/static/web/css` or `/app/static/css` is not created. Seem like, Django doesn't notice `/app/web/static` folder?

Comment: Check what's the value of `STATICFILES_DIRS`. And what is actually stored in `STATIC_ROOT`. You can print that out on the start of app.

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to make it work, by adding `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` and `STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web/static'),
]` in `settings.py`, and execute `collectstatic`.